# Is there a more coloquial word in English for refined carbohydrates?

Tags: synonyms

I mean, my language is Portuguese and we use the word "massa" as an umbrella term for foods like pizza, pasta, etc. Is there such a word in English? If so, what is it.

Comment: Does "massa" really mean refined carbohydrates?  "Refined carbohydrates" includes sugar (sucrose).  Would ice cream count as "massa"?  And on the flip side, whole wheat flour is not a refined carbohydrate.  Is whole wheat bread "massa"?

Comment: We don't usualy include sweet foods when we say massa. We also don't include whole wheat flour. It's usually the not sweet refined carbs like pizza or pasta.

Comment: Eu não acho que massa seja realmente genêricamente todos os hidratos de carbono refinados ou não em português. Carbs in English would include cake or pastry etc. It's all carbs because it is made with dough (massa). Carbs can refer to refined or unrefined carbohydrates.

Comment: massa is generically some types of food with carbohydrates: pasta and pizza, in Portuguese. Cake, which has carbs, is not massa, unless referring to the raw dough.

Comment: Massa can have two meaning. It can mean dough and in this case we include all carbs. So when you're preparing foods with flour, you need to the "massa". And another meaning is a n umbrella for foods made of flour that are usually not sweet.

Comment: Yes, I have already pointed that out. And I do not think that massa in Portuguese is a generic word for carbs, foods containing carbohydrates, only foods like pasta and pizza which do. However, in English, it means all foods with them.

Comment: Yes, you did. I don't know why but your comment was still not visible when I wrote mine.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we says **carbs.**

Low carb diets are in fashion now.

Massa is both carbs as in carbohydrates but is also used to mean just pasta.

massa italiana in Portuguese, generically, is just pasta in English.

massa de bolo is dough.

All are carbs.

So, in order to cover all the bases, in Portuguese, you have to say the whole thing: hidratos de carbono for carbs.

There is no short form in Portuguese to cover the idea of carbohydrates, carbs, as used in expressions like: eat a low carb diet.

Comment: Yeah, actually this is a better answer than mine.  "Carbs" is a common colloquialism.

Answer (score 1):

*"Starches"*, *"starchy foods"* or *"foods high in starch"* are common ways to describe these.  Although "starch" is a general term for both refined and unrefined carbohydrates, when talking about diet and nutrition, the term is often used with foods that quickly digest into simple sugars (and may therefore be more fattening).

> A: Let's go get a pizza?
>   B: Nah, I think I need to lose some weight so I'm trying to stay away from **starchy** foods.  How about a salad?

In general conversation, however, most people just called about *fattening* food without regard for its nutritional composition.  So starchy things like pasta can be lumped in with sugary foods like chocolate, or fatty foods like cheeseburgers.  After all, most foods are a combination of starches, protein, and fats.

(Edit) As per Lambie's answer, use "carbs" instead of "starch", e.g. "foods high in *carbs*", or, "I'm trying to lay off the *carbs* these days."